# Mass mail using AppleScript + CSV...But all emails have increased quote level on iOS

Tags: ios, email, applescript, apple-mail

I'm trying to send personalized, individual emails to a list of people on a CSV file using an AppleScript + Apple Mail. Everything's working great, except that the sent messages are displaying with the first quote level on iOS (and in other mail clients).

[Photo of indented quote level on iOS](https://share.cleanshot.com/FHrPZx)

Any ideas how to fix this?

```html
set {lastname, eAddress} to getData()

repeat with i from 1 to count lastname
    tell application "Mail"
        activate
        set mymail to make new outgoing message at the beginning of outgoing messages with properties {subject:"subject"}
        tell mymail
            make new to recipient at beginning of to recipients with properties {address:item i of eAddress}
            delay 0
            set content to "Hi Dr. " & lastname & "," & return & "Email Body"
            
        end tell
        --show message window (otherwise it's hidden)
        set visible of mymail to true
        --bring Mail to front
        activate
        send mymail
    end tell
end repeat


on getData()
    set colA to {}
    set colB to {}
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        
        activate
        tell active sheet
            set lastRow to first row index of (get end (last cell of column 1) direction toward the top)
            
            repeat with i from 3 to lastRow
                set end of colA to (value of range ("A" & i))
                set end of colB to (value of range ("B" & i))
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
    
    return {colA, colB}
end getData
```

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. when I run this script the salutation and email body get sent without any quote level applied. Is this the actual script you are running, or a cleaned-up version? Sometimes the devil is in the details...

Comment: That's the exact one.
Did you check the received messaged on iOS? I don't see any quote level applied when looking at the sent or received message in Mail on the Mac. It only shows on iOS or other mail clients (Fastmail).

Comment: I just ran a different script to send a message and ran into the same problem.

Comment: Ok, last update (sorry for all the posts; no clue what I'm doing really)..

When looking at the Raw Message, ">" is added to the content causing the quote level increase. There is also a blank line at the of each email.

If I remove the send command from the script, then manually remove the blank line from the body, and then manually click send, the message is sent properly.

Comment: I checked the sent email on my iPhone and it came through just fine, no quoting.  The only thing I can think is that your message is somehow getting forwarded rather than sent directly, because that's what I'd expect to see from a forwarded message. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think so? 

The same thing is happening with a super simple script too.(https://share.cleanshot.com/9qI6Og)

For some reason, the content is starting with a ">".  (https://share.cleanshot.com/TrCNeb)

And when i manually remove that blank first line, the quote level is normal on all devices.